# local notification with repeats

Tags: swift, push-notification, datepicker, notifications, nsdatecomponents

I am making a local notification that will run every year, the problem is that I need notifications that come based on the Hebrew calendar, that is, July 20, 2020 according to the Hebrew calendar 28 tamuz 5780 and if we add the year to 28 tamuz 5781 then according to the Gregorian calendar comes out on July 1, 2021, that is, according to the Gregorian calendar, the date changes, I also need to take into account the leap year, AnniversariesReminderService is responsible for the notification, thanks

July 20, ***2020*** is 28 tamuz ***5780***

***but***

28 tamuz ***5781*** is July 1, ***2021***

I need to automatically calculate this time difference so that every year I receive a notification according to the Jewish date

```
struct ReminderAnniversaries {
    
    var id:Int!
    var description:String!
    var date:Date!
    
}

class AnniversariesReminderService {
    
    fileprivate var formatter :DateFormatter {
        let dateformatterDay = DateFormatter()
        dateformatterDay.dateFormat = "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm"
        return dateformatterDay
    }
    
    func scheduleReminder(data: ReminderAnniversaries, complited: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        
        removeScheduledReminder(data: data)
        
        let request = self.prepareNotificationRequest(data: data)
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { error in
            if error != nil {
                print("ERROR SCHEDULE NOTIFICATION TYPE: \(String(describing: "\(data.id!)")), ERROR: \(String(describing:error?.localizedDescription))")
            }
            complited?()
        })
        
    }
    
    fileprivate func prepareNotificationRequest(data: ReminderAnniversaries) -> UNNotificationRequest {
        
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.sound = .default
        content.title = "AppDisplayName".localized()
        content.body = data.description
        let fireDate = data.date!
        var dateInfo = DateComponents()
        
        let triggerDaily = Calendar(identifier: .hebrew).dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .second], from: fireDate)
                
        dateInfo.year = fireDate.year
        dateInfo.month = fireDate.month
        dateInfo.day = fireDate.day
        dateInfo.hour = fireDate.hour
        dateInfo.minute = fireDate.minute + 1
        dateInfo.second = fireDate.second
        
        content.userInfo = ["id": data.id, "date" : fireDate,
                            "description": data.description]
        
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDaily, repeats: true)
        let requestIdentifier = "\(data.id!)"
        
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: requestIdentifier,
                                            content: content, trigger: trigger)
        print("NOTIFICATION SCHEDULED: (String(describing: requestIdentifier))")
        print("NOTIFICATION TITLE: \(String(describing: content.body))")
        print("NOTIFICATION TIME: \(String(describing:  self.formatter.string(from: fireDate)))")
        
        return request
        
    }
    
    func removeScheduledReminder(data: ReminderAnniversaries)  {
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: ["\(data.id!)"])
        print("NOTIFICATION REMOVED: \(String(describing:  "\(data.id!)"))")
        
    }
    
    func getScheduledReminderDate(data: ReminderAnniversaries) -> String? {
        
        var scheduledDate: Date?
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests { notifications in
            notifications.forEach({ notification in
                if let scheduledType = notification.content.userInfo["id"] as? Int, scheduledType == data.id {
                    scheduledDate = notification.content.userInfo["date"] as? Date ?? Date()
                    // continue;
                    semaphore.signal()
                }
            })
            if scheduledDate == nil {
                semaphore.signal()
            }
        }
        semaphore.wait()
        
        return scheduledDate != nil ? formatter.string(from: scheduledDate!) : nil
        
    }
}
```

Setting of date

```
@objc func doneDatePicker(){
        
        if isAlarmClock && stage != 1 {
            datePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
            pickerDone.setTitle("Done".localized(), for: .normal)
            pickerCancel.setTitle("Back".localized(), for: .normal)
            stage = 1
            formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm"
        } else if !isAlarmClock {
            //1
            formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
            formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
            let dateOfDied = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
            selectedDate = datePicker.date
          //  result Jule 21 2020 г.
            
            //2
            formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .hebrew) //convert to jewish date
            formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
            jewishDatePicker.date = datePicker.date
            
            jewishDatePicker.calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.hebrew)! as Calendar //convert to jewish calendar for adding year
            
            //count of years between date of died and current date
            let calendar = Calendar.current
            // Replace the hour (time) of both dates with 00:00
            let date1 = calendar.startOfDay(for: selectedDate)
            let date2 = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())
            let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year], from: date1, to: date2)
            
            var dayComponent = DateComponents()
            dayComponent.year = components.year! + 1
            
            let new_date = jewishDatePicker.calendar.date(byAdding: dayComponent, to: jewishDatePicker.date) // adding year by jewish calendar
            jewishSelectedDate = new_date!
            let hebDate = formatter.string(from: jewishSelectedDate)
            jewishDatePicker.locale = Locale(identifier: "he")
            jewishDatePicker.setDate(new_date!, animated: false)
            print(jewishDatePicker.date)
            //  result Jule 9 2021 г.
            
            //3
            formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian) //convert to gregorian date
            let gregDate = formatter.string(from: new_date!)
            //  result Jule 09 2021 г.
            
            alarmClock.isEnabled = true
            alarmClockBtn()
            var txt = Localized("You choosed", arguments: "\(dateOfDied)")
            txt = txt + " " + "Jewish anniversary falls on".localized() + " " + "\(gregDate) (\(hebDate))," + " " + "select the date and time to remind you".localized()
            text.text = txt
        } else {
            reminderTime = datePicker.date
            pickerView.isHidden = true
        }
        
    }
    

    @objc func addNotificationBtn(){
        
        if !(name.text?.isEmpty ?? false) && !(parentName.text?.isEmpty ?? false) &&
            jewishSelectedDate != nil && reminderTime != nil {
            errorNotifier.notify("Done".localized(), title: "Notification configured".localized(), showOK: true) { [weak self] in
                
                let remind = ReminderService()
                var txt = Localized("You have set an anniversary reminder", arguments: self!.name.text!)
                txt = txt + " " + "Бен(Бат)".localized() + " " + self!.parentName.text!
                let data = ReminderAnniversaries(id: 11, description: txt, date: self?.reminderTime)
                remind.anniversaries.scheduleReminder(data: data) {
                    print("ready")
                }
                self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        } else if (name.text?.isEmpty ?? false) && (parentName.text?.isEmpty ?? false) {
            errorNotifier.notify("Check the fields".localized(), title: "Fields must not be empty".localized(), showOK: true)
        } else if jewishSelectedDate == nil {
            errorNotifier.notify("Please select date if died".localized(), title:"", showOK: true)
        } else if reminderTime == nil {
            errorNotifier.notify("Please select a time for the anniversary reminder, the time is automatically set the day before the death anniversary".localized(), title: "Please select a time reminder".localized(), showOK: true)
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify your post?  The explanation text is a little hard to understand / read

Comment: @daredevil1234 I tried to do this, I hope it becomes clearer

Comment: Do I understand correctly : there is difference between how the gregorian and the roman calendar work. You want to schedule a local notification that repeats every year of the gregorian calendar and you think that the repeat method will repeat every year of the roman one.I'm right?

Comment: @Lapieuvre Yes, you got it right